# How to get source element from AJAX event?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have a table with controls in rows. I want to process another elements in the row when the input is changed:

```
        <p:inputText value="#{item.text}">
          <p:ajax event="change" onstart="refreshColumn(this)"/>
        </p:inputText>
```

However, 'this' is something that I can't identify here:

> Object { encodeViewState=function(), updateState=function(), updateElement=function(), mehr...}

Surely it doesn't contain `source` attribute, as that link would suggest: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14871

Is it possible (how) to get the element that triggered the event from `p:ajax` callbacks?

Comment: Note that in pure JSF (`f:ajax`) you can access the id of the calling element by using `data.source.id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the `event` instead....

***XHTML***

```
<p:inputText value="#{item.text}">
   <p:ajax event="change" onstart="refreshColumn(event)"/>
</p:inputText>
```

***JS***

```
function refreshColumn(event) {
   // "event.target.id" is the id of the inputText
   console.log(event.target.id)
}
```

---

The object that you are referring in the question is [`PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils`](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#731).

The PrimeFaces ajax/callback functions are [PrimeFaces.Behavior](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#548)s.

As for what you can pass more:

```
PrimeFaces.bc = function(source, event, ext, behaviorsArray) {
    PrimeFaces.Behavior.chain(source, event, ext, behaviorsArray);
}
```

The output of the change event should be something like this (passing only event):

```
PrimeFaces.bc(this, event, ext, ['PrimeFaces.ab({source:\'form:inputId\',event:\'change\',process:\'form:inputId\',onstart:function(cfg){refreshColumn(event);}}, arguments[1]);']);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I couldn't find in docs, what elements I can use in p:ajax callbacks.

Comment: I have explained more in the question, anyhow I have came up with this explanation based on the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/).. no official docs are available ...

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed