# How to get the source element of PrimeFaces pfAjaxStart event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a custom jQuery event handler for the pfAjaxStart event. I would like to register (or check inside) this handler only for events that come from an element with a specific css class, e.g. handle-ajax-start. How can I accomplish this.

```
$(document).on("pfAjaxStart", function(event, xhr, options) {
    /*
     * How to perform this only for events by elements with class handle-ajax-start???
     */
    console.log("Ajax Started...");
});
```

Comment: The event target is always related to the document, therefore there's no way to know who actually triggered the ajax event, [it's going to be always the document](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/c09bd655061920c6303e7d526631d590a3e1456d/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.ajax.js#L264).

Comment: What for is it good to have only global handlers?

Comment: Internally it's being used in [p:ajaxStatus](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/7a640b825cee43e0f874441df156525bd0321a32/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/ajaxstatus/ajaxstatus.js#L16). For users it's just a mark that an ajax event is going to start. in other cases, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937611/how-to-get-source-element-from-ajax-event) the ajax event is being explicitly triggred by the component (as target), meanwhile in the other case it's triggered on the document behalf (by desgin) so you can listen on the document (Global).

Answer (score 3):

With `pfAjaxStart`, your closest bet is [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement).

```
$(document).on("pfAjaxStart", function(event) {
    var $source = $(document.activeElement);
    // ...
});
```

Given that you also specified `xhr` and `options`, which actually aren't present during `pfAjaxStart` (and is fixed above), I believe you *actually* intend to hook on `pfAjaxSend`. The ID of the source element in the DOM is then available via `options.source`. This may be more reliable than `document.activeElement`.

```
$(document).on("pfAjaxSend", function(event, xhr, options) {
    var $source = $(document.getElementById(options.source));
    // ...
});
```

Comment: In my experience the activeElement is not always accurate. As for pfAjaxSend it would surely work, but in some cases it's too late, for example to cancel the event. It depends on the requirement of the OP. But yes this is the closest thing he can get... :)